# Dynamic routes with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I have a task to develop a rails application following the model for routing.

I need to have `PageController` and `Page` model. Page urls must be like `/contacts, /shipping, /some_page`.

Also i need have `CatalogController` and `Category` model. Categories urls must be like `/laptops, /smartphones/android`.

And it will be `ProductsController` and `Product` model, urls of products must be line `/laptops/toshiba_sattelite_l605`, `/smartphones/android/htc_magic`

I understand that this problem can be solved by using URLs like

- `/page/shipping`
- `/catalog/smartphones/android`

But the customer does not want to see the insertion of "`/page`" or "`/catalog`" in the URL.

Please tell me the direction for solving this problem.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: How will you distinguish if `/something` is a page or a category?

Comment: It may be category(/laptops) or it may be page (/contacts). Of cause i understand that Category and Page models need to have some field, say "slug", and it must be unique along the site.

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  If they're worried about the url's being "ugly", then they can do something like `/faq/contacts` or `/questions/shipping`.

Comment: Checkout the official Rails routing guide @ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Did you find a Solution on this I'm also interrested... but google didn't help me :( I use friendly_id that has generated a table slugs with the slug name, it's id and the controler name(sluggable_type) fields... but no documentation shows how to use that for routing purpose. Any help would be welcome. Regards.

Comment: I used the solution described in the first answer. Unfortunately, I do not know any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You'll have to write a "catch-all" rule:

On routes.rb:

```
get '*my_precioussss' => 'sauron#one_action_to_rule_them_all'
```

Your precious controller:

```
class SauronController < ApplicationController
  def one_action_to_rule_them_all
    @element = find_by_slug(params[:my_precioussss])
    render @element.kind # product, category, etc
  end
end
```

Then you write one view for each "kind" of element: product.html.erb, category.html.erb, etc.

Make sure you write your `find_by_slug` implementation.

You can change `one_action_to_rule_them_all` to `pikachu_i_choose_you` and `SauronController` to `PokemonController`, will work too.

Comment: upvoting solely based on the example ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a catch all

```
match '*page' => 'pages#show'
```

then handle the page path in your page controller

```
def show
  if params[:page] 
    @page = Page.find_by_page(params[:page])
  else
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end
...
```

if you use Omniauth or another rails lib that uses it's own catch all you may need to exclude some urls from this, use a lambda in your constraint

```
match '*page' => 'pages#show', :constraints => lambda{|req|  !req.env["REQUEST_URI"].include? "auth"}
```

If you want to have nested paths (e.g. "smartphones/android") you'll need to split the :page param apart and handle the path segments in your controller

```
path = :page.split("/")  // you now have an array of path segments you can use in your controller
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this guide to rails 3 routing incredibly helpful:

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 1):

i have done it in combination of two approaches

1. use friendly_id gem to operate with slugs in find requests instead of numeric ids
2. define routes with `:constraints=>ConditionClass` which has to return `true` or `false` (so route will be determined or not)

small example:

```
#routes.rb
    class CategoryBrandGoodConstraint
      def self.matches?(request)
        path_parts = request.path.split('/')
        Category.find(path_parts[1]).present?&&Brand.find(path_parts[2]).present?&&Good.find(path_parts[3]).present? rescue false
      end
    end

    get ':category_friendly_id/:brand_friendly_id/:good_friendly_id' => 'goods#index', :constraints => CategoryBrandGoodConstraint
    #another conditional routes with another :constraints=>ConditionClass2 definition
    #...
    #until you define all necessary conditional application routes

#goods_controller.rb

    def index

      #operate with params[:category_friendly_id], params[:brand_friendly_id], params[:good_friendly_id] to collect all you need for view rendering

    end
```

of course, you can route to another controller to render another view `get '/:whatever' => 'another_controller#another_action', :constraints=>ConditionClassN`

hope it helps!

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Rails routes are based solely on URL. If you don't have `/pages` or `/categories` or whatever before the name, then how is Rails going to tell if a URL like `http://example.com/smartphones` is a page URL or category URL? Unless you have some predefined list of pages names in the routes conditions, it cannot.

The only way to do that in this example would be to actually search for a page by `smartphones` and if none is found assume that this is a category name and search for a category. This can't be done in rails routes. To do that, you'd need a single controller that would handle all those URLs and do that search and then render a proper template (you can't redirect, because that would change the url). And that is an ugly way to solve this problem.

If I were you I'd try to convince the customer to agree on some kind of prefix (like `/p_pagename`) or preferably different URLs. It could be something like `/p/shipping` for pages and all other URLs could be routed to `CategoriesController` or `ProductsController`.

Comment: I agree with your position, but it absolutely impossible to convince the customer to agree on some kind of prefix in URLs. His SEO needs such URLs. So i need to find solution.