# Rails 3: making a catch-all route easier to read and amend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, catch-all

I'm trying to write a catch-all route in Rails 3, but I want to reserve some terms in it.  I'm specifically following the example put forth in this post, in the answer by David Burrows: [Dynamic routes with Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195880/dynamic-routes-with-rails-3)

The syntax I am using is the following:

```
match '*path' => 'router#routing', :constraints => lambda{|req|  (req.env["REQUEST_PATH"] =~ /(users|my-stuff)/).nil? }
```

Now, that syntax works just fine - if a user visits a page with "user" or "my-stuff" in the path, it falls through the catch-all and goes to a specific place.  If the user goes to any other URL, it goes to my routing logic.

My question is more about readability - is there a way I can match the route against something *other* than a regex?  Is there a way to provide an array of terms to match against?  Also, is there a way to match specific segments of the route, as opposed to the entire thing?

Obviously Rails has built-in routing, but this project has a requirement that for certain routes, the controller not be present in the URL.  Hence, the catch-all.

Thanks for any help

Here's the updated routes file per the answer below:

```
class RouteConstraint
  RESERVED_ROUTES = ['users', 'my-stuff']

  def matches?(request)
    !RESERVED_ROUTES.map {|r| request.path.include?(r)}.empty?
  end
end

App::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories
  resources :sites

  match '*path' => 'router#routing', :constraints => RouteConstraint.new

  devise_for :users, :path_names =>{ :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :registration => 'register' }
  root :to => "router#routing"
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a class to specify the constraints if you want something cleaner once you have multiple routes to try:

```
class MyConstraint
  BYPASSED_ROUTES = ['users', 'my-stuff']

  def matches?(request)
    BYPASSED_ROUTES.map {|r| request.path.include?(r)} .empty?
  end
end

TwitterClone::Application.routes.draw do
  match "*path" => "router#routing", :constraints => MyConstraint.new
end
```

This example is adapted from the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

Comment: This gets close, but now instead of bypassing the "hidden routes" listed, the logic tries to feed them to the routing controller.  If I remove the bang or the .empty? call in the matches method, the logic works for reserved words, but not for everything else.  Sorry, my grasp of lambdas is pretty limited.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question then, my logic was the exact opposite of yours. Could you post a bit more of your routes files, to see how the catch-all fits in there?

Comment: Ok, I've added the current routes to my question above.

Comment: Catch-all routes are usually put at the very end, have you any particular reason for putting it in the middle?

Comment: Moving it to the end fixed the problem.  I didn't have any reason to have it in the middle at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking a lambda; you can use whatever criteria you want.