# Rails: match the url to base url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple quick question. I have a Url:

```
  http://www.mealnut.com/foodios/cakerystore
```

Need to make it as

```
  http://www.mealnut.com/cakerystore
```

Can anybody tell how to do this? I am new to rails.

Comment: This question needs more detail.  Is `foodios` a controller?  Is `cakerystore` an action?  Is there a model with whatever controller this is?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Yes it is foodios controller. cakerystore is user's name. And there is no model with controller.

Comment: Oh, wow.  That might be a tough one.  Does this mean that you want to do this with *every* username?

Comment: Alright, I think I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still very unclear, but I think you need a catch-all rule in your routes.rb:

```
get "*username" => "foodios#user_action"
```

This will allow you to have root urls for each user, which is what I think you're really asking for:

- `http://www.mealnut.com/cakerystore`
- `http://www.mealnut.com/bakeland`
- `http://www.mealnut.com/cookieworld`
- etc

**This should be *last* route defined in your routes.rb file.**  That's because this route will match *all* URLs not matched by other routes defined earlier in the file.  (Rails attempts to match routes in the order that they are defined.)

This route directs the url to the `FoodiosController::user_action` action (e.g. method).  (You can rename `user_action`, of course.)

This action would be defined something like this:

```
# In FoodiosController

def user_action
  # params[:username] comes from '*username' in the route
  @user = User::find_by_username(params[:username])

  unless @user.nil?
    # not sure what you want to show, but this would do user#show 
    render @user
    # or you can render some other path
  else
    # redirect to some error page
  end
end
```

Because this route catches *everything*, that else case in there will need to do something appropriate for not just invalid usernames, but any kind of bad URL you may get.  It's all controlled by this action now.

For what it's worth, I think you'd be better off not doing it this way.  It sounds like you should have a UsersController, and your URL should be `http://www.mealnut.com/users/cakerystore`.  It would be so much easier.

Credit/further reading:

- [Fabio Batista's answer to "Dynamic routes with Rails 3"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4226438/650475)
- [Dynamic Routing With Rails post by Josh Symonds](http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2012/05/22/dynamic-routing-with-rails/)
- [Route Globbing section, from the Routing Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is the answer to your problem. But it is the answer to your question.

```
'http://www.mealnut.com/foodios/cakerystore'.gsub(/\/foodios/,'')
```

Comment: not working. I am doing this: <td style="float:right"><%= link_to "by #{product.user.profile.brand_name}", "/foodios/#{p.user.profile.brand_name}", :class => "p_foodio"  %> to get above url.

Comment: Why do you not just use: `<%= link_to "by #{product.user.profile.brand_name}", "#{p.user.profile.brand_name}", :class => "p_foodio" %>` to get rid of the `foodios` part?

Comment: Or did you mean: "How can I configure my Rails app to connect  http://www.mealnut.com/foodios/cakerystore with http://www.mealnut.com/cakerystore?" That would be a routing task. Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/routes.html