# Ruby on Rails: dynamic multi-path to one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

In Rails 4, I have 3 models

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :id, :name
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :id, :name
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :id, :name
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :category
  delegate :tag_name, to: :tag
  delegate :category_name, to: :category
end
```

Now I have a tag `id: 1, name: "tag1"` and a category `id: 1, name: "category1"`, and a Product with `name: "product1", tag_id: 1, category_id: 1`

I want to match route to `product` with both `tag` and `category` in URL. Ex:

```
/tag1/category1/product1
/category1/tag1/product1
/tag1/product1
/category1/product1
/product1
```

but don't know how to add it automatically. ( I use `friendly_id` gem to make URL become more friendly)
Here the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067005/1730761) that I use to match the route, but it isn't dynamic as I want. When the requirement not only `tag` and `category`, but also `sub_category`, `super_category`... the `routes.rb` will increase very fast and doesn't `DRY`

Can anyone give me another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ugly solution of what you want:

```
#routes.rb
match "(:first_id)/(:second_id)/(:third_id)", to: "home#index", via: :get
```

as you mentioned, you need last params and that will be product id. So we just need to get last one.

```
#home controller
def index
  product_id = case 
  when params[:third_id].present?
    params[:third_id]
  when params[:second_id].present?
    params[:second_id]
  when params[:first_id].present?
    params[:first_id]
  end
 @product = Product.find(product_id)
end
```