# Enrypt url in browser in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am working in a project in Rails 4.

```
localhost:3000/employees/view
```

How may I encrypt the url which is coming in browser in rails for whole application. Whichever link I click, the url must be encrypted as showing the url of the page may be unsafe as its displaying the name of the table. So please help.

Comment: Try and search google for "Rails obfuscate url". Or even checkout [this gem](https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id).  [Here is a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289515/obfuscation-of-urls-rails) to yours.

Comment: will you suggest me best available gem for it.

Comment: I can't, because I never had to implement URL obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

> may be unsafe as its displaying the name of the table

That's a popular myth among inexperienced developers. Url obfuscation makes the site unusable to humans (they now can't tell one page from another), will complicate your code immensely and, most importantly, **will not add any security**.

I mean, if you have a blog site, for example, one can assume, with high degree of confidence, that you have a table named `posts`. Now we're back to square one, only now we have ugly urls.

If your concern is security of your site, I suggest that you learn proper techniques and tools/libraries for authentication, authorization, etc.

Here's the official recommendation: [Avoid Security by Obscurity](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Security_by_Design_Principles#Avoid_security_by_obscurity).